# Meaning of XMLElement@required=true

Tags: jax-ws, cxf

Does it mean the XML element is mandatory ? Or the XML element must have some non-null value ? I am really confused by the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) explanation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
@XMLElement(required=true)
```

generates something like this in the XML schema:

```
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
```

which means the element and a value are mandatory. The default is false.

This:

```
@XMLELement(nillable=true)
```

generates something like this in the XML schema:

```
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
```

which means you can pass in a nil value in your XML like this:

```
<city xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Combining the two like this:

```
@XMLELement(nillable=true, required=true)
```

gives an XML schema definition similar to this:

```
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
```

which means the element is mandatory but you can pass in a nil value.

Answer (score 5):

[If required() is true, then Javabean property is mapped to an XML schema element declaration with minOccurs="1"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#required%28%29)

The `minOccurs` indicator specifies the minimum number of times an element can occur. If element in the schema has `minOccurs="1"` attribute this means that the element is mandatory. It must appear in the `XML` document.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to dig into my question. I have clarified by creating a simple test harness. The mandatory constraint applies to both the element and its value.